# Center array of objects in relation to another object

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects, edges, faces

I started to play around with Blender's Array Modifier and created an array of four cylinders which worked quite well.

However, I want to center that array on the top face of the object below the array in both x- and y-direction.

[image]

Since I have a 3D-CAD and some Inkscape background I am looking for a function like "center object" or "align object" which I can provide the boundary faces or edges to but was not able to find such a function.

How could I achieve the desired result? Is there a function I missed or if not, what is a preferable workflow for doing such alignment tasks?

As I said, coming from a 3D-CAD background, my first impression to Blender is that it seems to "think" somehow different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Space</kbd> and write *align objects* into the search box that appears, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: Space menu]

Then on the *undo panel* on the bottom left click on X and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>-click on Y

[image]

Finally to place exactly on top, enable snapping to vertex and move along the Z axis only (either by dragging the arrow or with <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>

The place where the mouse is when you hit <kbd>G</kbd> *usually* denotes the vertex you want to snap to the point the mouse is when you click to release. I say usually because depending on the camera angle blender might misunderstand your intentions.

[image: snap]